# How to delete data from 2 tables mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with a MySQL database. I want to delete user about id=1 using this query "`delete from user where user_id =1`".

At this moment should be delete a user, and also every his post from table "post". The problem is that user is deleted, but his post in table "post" not delete.
EDIT: I try to create a table using InnoDB engine, but show me error.

```
CREATE TABLE `post` (
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `date_to_add` date NOT NULL,
  `time_to_add` time NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES user(`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci;



CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `login` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` tinytext COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci;
```

Comment: You have two tables without any relationship between them. Why would you expect that updating one table should impact the other?

Comment: You need to create a foreign key constraint that will cascade your delete, the database doesn't know to do this by default.

Comment: I changed my code. but now that not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE
FROM user
JOIN post USING (user_id)
```

But I'd recommend to create foreign key with `ON DELETE CASCADE` option - in such case deleting from `user` deletes all related rows from `post`.

---

> During create a table 'post' show me error Code error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci; ` – kowal20

Unrelated error, but I'll answer. See <kbd>**[DEMO fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=979878c809d549691550e195a249c05c)**</kbd>.

Comment: During create a table 'post' show me error Code error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed 
  FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES user(`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci;
`

Comment: @kowal20 Updated.